# Unable to import java.time.Duration in PeriodicWorkRequest class (WorkManager)

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Getting Cannot resolve symbol for import java.time.Duration in PeriodicWorkRequest class.

Java: 8
JDK: 1.8.0_191[image]
implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha10'

Comment: `java.time.Duration` is available on API 26+. Is your `compileSdkVersion` >= 26?

Comment: Thanks Sergey! You can post this as an answer, so that I can mark it as accept.

Comment: Careful, that will only allow you to use your app on API 26 or later.

Comment: But it will still run on older devices, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that `compileSdkVersion` is set to 26 or higher because `java.time.Duration` is available only on API 26+. This won't affect the ability to run your app on devices with a lower API level.