# Nativescript: Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.time.Duration while using WorkManager

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

Hey I am implementing a service that requests background location on every hour using Nativesript 6.5 + Angular in Android. For that purpose I am using androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest. The following code works fine on devices with API level higher that 26.

```
 @JavaProxy('com.tns.BackgroundLocationService')
 export class BackgroundLocationService extends (<any>androidx).work.Worker {
     constructor(context, params) {
         super(context, params);
         return global.__native(this);
         }
  public doWork() {
   // some work here for getting the geolocation

       return (<any>androidx).work.ListenableWorker.Result.success();
   }
   public onStopped() {
  console.log("onStopped from MyWorker !!!")
 }
}
```

And for running the Worker I use the following Typescript class:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyWorkerHandler {

constructor() {
}

getJobConstrains() {
    return (new (<any>androidx).work.Constraints.Builder()).build();
}

getWorkRequest() {
    let constrains = this.getJobConstrains();
    return (new (<any>androidx).work.PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(java.lang.Class.forName("com.tns.BackgroundLocationService"), 15, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES))
        .setConstraints(constrains)        
        .build()
}

enqueue() {
    let worker = this.getWorkRequest();        
    ((<any>androidx).work.WorkManager).getInstance()
      .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("sediDomaChallenger", (<any>androidx).work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, worker); 
}
}
```

As mentioned this code works fine in versions above 26. But when running it on on devices with lower SDK I get the following error:

```
JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.time.Duration
```

I did found this thread on stackoverflow [Unable to import java.time.Duration in PeriodicWorkRequest class (WorkManager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996714/unable-to-import-java-time-duration-in-periodicworkrequest-class-workmanager), but from what I saw I am compiling my code on version 29. The WorkManager works on every Android version when I am using OneTimeWorkRequest.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? I assume it has something to do with configuring out NS, or maybe I am not understanding Android well, at the end of the day I am a web developer :)

Tnx in advance <3

Comment: Which version of AndroidX your project is using? This seems to a bug in Android X 1.0.0, using a later version should fix the issue.

Comment: How can I check that? I just switched my project to use androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.1.0 and I get the same issue.

Comment: And also I use androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.4 but still the same issue.

Comment: Can you share a sample project where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Hey I made a repo where I replicated the issue. Just run the code on devices with an API lvl lower than 26, https://github.com/StefanAleksik/WorkManger . Thank you very much for the effort I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Manoj did you had a chance to take a look?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be {N} issue, use version `2.4.0-alpha02` where I think this is addressed.

Comment: Ah it does not make a difference :(

Comment: Then I would suggest you to raise an issue at [android-runtime](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues).

Answer (score 0):

java.time was only added with Android 8 (api 26)
You can make it available in lower versions via coreLibraryDesugaring

Edit your build.gradle:

```
compileOptions {
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

And add this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.3'
    ..
```

If it does not work right away like in my project do a build-> clean Project + rebuild Project